# Tags as autocomplete values

Tags: tags, autocomplete

How can I load regular post tags as values for autocomplete field? What I have now is pretermined values like this:

```
var data = {items: [
{value: "1", name: "Siemens"},
{value: "2", name: "Phillips"},
{value: "3", name: "Whirlpool"},
{value: "4", name: "LG"}
};
$("#input_1_3").autoSuggest(data.items, {selectedItemProp: "name", searchObjProps: "name"});
```

I'm using Drew Wilson's Autocomplete plugin found at: http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin. Any help would be most apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_GET['get_tags'])):
  $output = array();
  foreach(get_terms('post_tag') as $key => $term):
    // filter by $_GET['q'] here if you need to,
    // for eg. if(strpos($term->name, $_GET['q']) !== false)...
    $output[$key]['value'] = $key;
    $output[$key]['name'] = $term->name;
  endforeach;

  header("Content-type: application/json");
  echo json_encode($output);
  die();
endif;
```

in this case your js would be something like:

```
$("#input_1_3").autoSuggest(
    "http://yoursite.com/?get_tags=1",
    {selectedItemProp: "name", searchObjProps: "name"});
```

Comment: Where exactly the `if(isset($_GET['get_tags'])):` snippet goes, because i haven't been able to get it to work? The autocomplete itself works with your code, it just doesen't get the tags as values.

Comment: in your theme functions, or a plugin..

Comment: Now I know what the problem is: The autocomplete won't suggest tags without any posts assigned to them. Any ideas how to show the "empty" tags? Other than that your code clearly works, so thank you very, very much!

Comment: point your browser to `http://yoursite.com/?get_tags=1`. All tags you see there should also shown by the AC plugin. If not, you might need to filter them by `$_GET['q']` (ie. get only the tags that contain the characters entered by the user)

Comment: Great, thank you very much. I got everyhting in order now. Much respect!

Comment: One more thing for future referene: How about custom taxonomies? Now it works flawlessly with regular post tags, but gives an error if I change the `(get_terms('post_tag') as...` to something else, i.e `(get_terms('new_tag') as...` and type `http://yoursite.com/?get_tags=1` on the browser. The error is like this: `{"errors":{"value":"errors","name":null},"error_data":{"value":"error_data","name":null}}`

Comment: see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms (`new_tag` must be a taxonomy, not a term)

Comment: `new_tag` is a taxonomy, but the error persists. I'm thinking the problem is somehow connected to the fact that the `new_tag` is connected to a custom post type, not the wordpress standard post type.

Comment: no, there shoudn't be any problems with that. do you have any terms in that taxonomy that are associated to posts?

Comment: Sorry to take so long, but yeah, that was the problem. Again. Everything works fine when there's posts assigned to the taxonomies. Thank you very much one again.

Comment: this is what I did https://stackoverflow.com/a/51345915/1018804